# How to clean data with two delimiters using Python?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, data-cleaning

I have multiple lines of text in a single column.
One Column for example looks like:- NIKE// RT-2 \n PUMA// AB-C \n NIKE// QE-3-R

I don't need data between "//" and "\n". I just need the brand names such as Nike, Puma and I need their count.
For example, in this case I would like to know that there are two Nike's and one Puma in this column.

I am a beginner user of Python. Have been trying to work at this problem for weeks now, and still no break through. I would appreciate any help you folks can provide. Cheers.

Comment: Please provide a proper reproducible example with sample input and expected output.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! A few more columns, along with what you are looking for as an input would be really helpful. It'd also be nice if you could format it with markdown.

Answer (score 0):

In pure Python, you could try this:

```py
import re
from collections import Counter

row = "NIKE// RT-2 \n PUMA// AB-C \n NIKE// QE-3-R"

counts = Counter([item.replace("//", "") for item in re.findall("\w+//", row)])

print(counts)  # Counter({'NIKE': 2, 'PUMA': 1})
```

From here, you just have to iterate on each row.

Answer (score 0):

This seemed like a good place to use regular expressions. Regular Expressions (or regex) are special strings that can extract specific patterns of text from strings. (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression)

For your example, the string '''.+(?=//)''' fits it perfectly. It basically tells the computer to look for things in between `\n` and `\\` and return the text. In my example code, I use the regular expression to return a list.

```
import re

regex = r".+(?=//)"

test_str = ("NIKE// RT-2\n"
    "PUMA// AB-C\n"
    "NIKE// QE-3-R\n")

matches = re.findall(regex, test_str, re.MULTILINE) #["NIKE", "PUMA", "NIKE"]

results = dict((brand,matches.count(brand)) for brand in set(matches))

print(results)
```

The `re.findall` function extracts the text to a list (see the comment). Afterwards I used a dictionary comprehension to create a dictionary that shows the count of each brand. (https://www.datacamp.com/community/tutorials/python-dictionary-comprehension)

The final output is:

```
{'NIKE': 2, 'PUMA': 1}
```